# Keypress Pause and Play Audio

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I'm working on an audio player and I want people to be able to play and pause music with the spacebar. I have it working. Unfortunately, the script only works on the first player (when someone clicks a song, a player partial is loaded at the top of the screen). So once the first partial is gone. It the play and pause function doesn't work again. Any suggestions.

```
$(document).keydown(function(event) {
  if (event.keyCode == 32) {
    if (!mytrack.paused && !mytrack.ended) {
      mytrack.pause();
      play.innerHTML = "<i class='fa fa-play'></i>";
      window.clearInterval(updateTime);
    } else {
      mytrack.play();
      play.innerHTML = "<i class='fa fa-pause'></i>";
      updateTime = setInterval(update, 500);
    }
    return false;
  }
});
```

---

Full Code

```
    var mytrack = document.getElementById("sound");
var play = document.getElementById("play");
var currentTime = document.getElementById("current-time");
var totalTime = document.getElementById("total-time");
var defaultBar = document.getElementById("default-bar");
var progressBar = document.getElementById("progress-bar");
var barSize;

defaultBar.addEventListener('click', clickedBar, false);

mytrack.addEventListener('loadedmetadata', function () {
  mytrack.play();
  updateTime = setInterval(update, 500);
  play.innerHTML = "<i class='fa fa-pause'></i>";
  var minutes = parseInt(mytrack.duration / 60);
  var seconds = parseInt(mytrack.duration % 60);
  if (seconds < 10) {
    totalTime.innerHTML = minutes + ":0" + seconds;
  } else {
    totalTime.innerHTML = minutes + ":" + seconds;
  }
});

function playOrPause() {
  if (!mytrack.paused && !mytrack.ended) {
    mytrack.pause();
    play.innerHTML = "<i class='fa fa-play'></i>";
    window.clearInterval(updateTime);
  } else {
    mytrack.play();
    play.innerHTML = "<i class='fa fa-pause'></i>";
    updateTime = setInterval(update, 500);
  }
}

function update() {
  if(!mytrack.ended) {
    // CURRENT TIME TO READABLE TIME
    var minutes = parseInt(mytrack.currentTime / 60);
    var seconds = parseInt(mytrack.currentTime % 60);
    if (seconds < 10) {
      currentTime.innerHTML = minutes + ":0" + seconds;
    } else {
      currentTime.innerHTML = minutes + ":" + seconds;
    }
    // BAR
    var progressBarSize = parseInt(mytrack.currentTime * barSize /mytrack.duration);
    progressBar.style.width = progressBarSize + "px";
    barSize = defaultBar.offsetWidth;
  } else {
    currentTime.innerHTML = "0:00";
    play.innerHTML = "<i class='fa fa-play'></i>";
    // Bar
    progressBar.style.width = "0px";
    // TIMER
    window.clearInterval(updateTime);
  }
}

function clickedBar(e) {
  if(!mytrack.ended) {
    var mouseX = e.pageX - defaultBar.offsetLeft;
    var newTime = mouseX * mytrack.duration/barSize;
    mytrack.currentTime = newTime;
    progressBar.style.width = mouseX + "px";
  }
}
```

Comment: Where/when is `myTrack` created? If that's your first player and you then create more, the handler you have right now only knows about `myTrack`

Comment: Ill edit the post with the full player code. The player is loaded in a partial. So only one player is actually on the page at a time. When you click a new song, the previous disappears. Thanks for the comment!

Comment: Maybe it's because you are binding the click event listener to the first partial, but once the first partial is gone, the event is not bound to the second partial (player), if that makes sense. Have a function that re-binds it after the next player is loaded.

Comment: It may help to look into [event delegation](https://davidwalsh.name/event-delegate) as well.

Answer (score 0):

Your `mytrack` is set once at the outset.

```
var mytrack = document.getElementById("sound");
```

In the course of using your app if a "new player" is put in place such that `mytrack` is no longer in the DOM, your reference to `mytrack` is now pointing to an audio element that isn't useful anymore.

You either need to not replace `mytrack` and instead change the src dynamically such that `mytrack` remains in the DOM or update your reference to your audio element as needed.

This could be as simple as updating `mytrack = document.getElementById("whatever-the-id-of-the-new-audio-element-is");` after replacing it, or finding it dynamically each before you try to interact with it.

In short, your closures retain a reference to `mytrack` and will always try to use it. It's your job to make sure it remains useful, or replace it.

EDIT just looked at all your expanded code and noticed you're attaching listeners to `myTrack`. You'll need to pair each `addEventListner` with a corresponding `removeEventListener` when you remove `myTrack` from the DOM to avoid memory leaks.

You'll probably want to move all the "code to execute when you start observing a player" into a function so you can use it for each audio player you setup. Event delegation, listening for events at a higher level, aren't really what you're looking for as most of the HTML5 media event do not bubble.

Once you have that code isolated, you'll also need a set for reacting to the removal of an audio element.

Keep in mind that `addEventListener` and `removeEventListener` expect to be called on the same element, for the same event type, with the same handler, at the same event phase. This is what often trips up people unfamiliar with the process and send them to setting `onended` directly on the element. But it's not that complicated. There are plenty of issues here on SO about `removeEventListener` "not working" that will explain.